# Having problem to publish a message in Pub/Sub using Python from Airflow

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to publish a message in Pub/Sub but I get this error:

```
[2021-08-30 23:10:55,317] {taskinstance.py:1049} ERROR - 'Future' object has no attribute '_condition'
Traceback (most recent call last)
  File "/usr/local/lib/airflow/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 1046, in _run_raw_tas
    task.on_success_callback(context
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/plugins/logger.py", line 70, in on_success_task_instanc
    log_monitoring(DAG_STATE_SUCCESS, context=context
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/plugins/logger.py", line 220, in log_monitorin
futures.wait(publish_futures, return_when=futures.ALL_COMPLETED
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 284, in wai
    with _AcquireFutures(fs)
  File "/opt/python3.6/lib/python3.6/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 146, in __enter_
    future._condition.acquire(
AttributeError: 'Future' object has no attribute '_condition
```

The code is the following:

```
# Publishes multiple messages to a Pub/Sub topic with an error handler. 
from concurrent import futures
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from typing import Any, Callable

topic_path = 'projects/.../topics/test_log_monitoring'
publish_futures = []

publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

def get_callback(
    publish_future: pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future, data: str
) -> Callable[[pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future], None]:
    def callback(publish_future: pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future) -> None:
        try:
            # Wait 60 seconds for the publish call to succeed.
            print(publish_future.result(timeout=60))
        except futures.TimeoutError:
            print(f"Publishing {data} timed out.")

    return callback

record = {
    'Key1': 'Value1',
    'Key2': 'Value2',
    'Key3': 'Value3'
}

data = json.dumps(record).encode("utf-8")
# When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
publish_future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
# on-blocking. Publish failures are handled in the callback function.
publish_future.add_done_callback(get_callback(publish_future, data))
publish_futures.append(publish_future)

# Wait for all the publish futures to resolve before exiting.
futures.wait(publish_futures, return_when=futures.ALL_COMPLETED)

print(f"Published messages with error handler to {topic_path}.")
```

By the way, I'm following this official tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publish-with-error-handler

Do you have any idea what's wrong?

To end, Is there different some way to wait message published?

Comment: Maybe this version is not compatible: from `concurrent` import futures. The python code is trying to implicitly use future._condition but it does not exist.

Comment: I used your code and it worked fine for me. I was able to publish a message. A minor thing that I changed is that in `record` I changed Value1... to string. I'm using **google-cloud-pubsub==2.7.1** when I tested this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue using the code snippet. I used **Composer version 1.16.15** and **Airflow version 1.10.15**. I did not install any extra python libraries on mine.

To fix this, update your Pubsub to the latest version which is 2.7.1 in your Cloud Composer instance. You can update it using the command `gcloud composer environments update`. See [Installing a Python dependency from PyPI](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-package) for more details.

To be able to smoothly update the Pubsub library, explicitly define the Google libraries in your `requirements.txt`. This is because Google libraries are dependent to other Google libraries see [Pubsub library dependencies](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/blob/main/testing/constraints-3.6.txt). You can get the pre installed Google libraries in [Cloud Composer pre installed packages](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/versioning/composer-versions) reference. But if you have updated Google libraries, you can just include the versions that you use in the `requirements.txt`.

**requirements.txt**

```
google-ads==4.0.0
google-api-core==1.26.1
google-api-python-client==1.12.8
google-apitools==0.5.31
google-auth==1.28.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.3
google-cloud-automl==2.2.0
google-cloud-bigquery==2.13.0
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer==3.1.0
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.1.0
google-cloud-bigtable==1.7.0
google-cloud-build==2.0.0
google-cloud-container==1.0.1
google-cloud-core==1.6.0
google-cloud-datacatalog==3.1.0
google-cloud-dataproc==2.3.0
google-cloud-datastore==1.15.3
google-cloud-dlp==1.0.0
google-cloud-kms==2.2.0
google-cloud-language==1.3.0
google-cloud-logging==2.2.0
google-cloud-memcache==0.3.0
google-cloud-monitoring==2.0.0
google-cloud-os-login==2.1.0
google-cloud-pubsub==2.7.1
google-cloud-pubsublite==0.3.0
google-cloud-redis==2.1.0
google-cloud-secret-manager==1.0.0
google-cloud-spanner==1.19.1
google-cloud-speech==1.3.2
google-cloud-storage==1.36.2
google-cloud-tasks==2.2.0
google-cloud-texttospeech==1.0.1
google-cloud-translate==1.7.0
google-cloud-videointelligence==1.16.1
google-cloud-vision==1.0.0
google-cloud-workflows==0.2.0
google-crc32c==1.1.2
google-pasta==0.2.0
google-resumable-media==1.2.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.53.0
graphviz==0.16
greenlet==1.0.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.3
grpcio==1.38.1
grpcio-gcp==0.2.2
```

**Update command:**

```
gcloud composer environments update your-environrment-name --update-pypi-packages-from-file requirements.txt --location your-composer-location
```

**When installed it will return done:**
[image]

**Check version in GCP Console-> Composer-> your-environment -> PYPI Packages:**

[image]

**Airflow test run:**
[image]

**Airflow logs:**
[image]

**DAG used:**

```
import datetime

import airflow
from airflow.operators import bash_operator
from airflow.operators import python_operator
import json
from concurrent import futures
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1
from typing import Any, Callable

YESTERDAY = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'Composer Example',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': YESTERDAY,
}

def publish_error_handle():
    topic_path = 'projects/your-project-id/topics/test-topic'
    publish_futures = []

    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient()

    def get_callback(
        publish_future: pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future, data: str
    ) -> Callable[[pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future], None]:
        def callback(publish_future: pubsub_v1.publisher.futures.Future) -> None:
            try:
                # Wait 60 seconds for the publish call to succeed.
                print(publish_future.result(timeout=60))
            except futures.TimeoutError:
                print(f"Publishing {data} timed out.")

        return callback

    record = {
        'Key1': 'Value1',
        'Key2': 'Value2',
        'Key3': 'Value3'
    }

    data = json.dumps(record).encode("utf-8")
    # When you publish a message, the client returns a future.
    publish_future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data)
    # on-blocking. Publish failures are handled in the callback function.
    publish_future.add_done_callback(get_callback(publish_future, data))
    publish_futures.append(publish_future)

    # Wait for all the publish futures to resolve before exiting.
    futures.wait(publish_futures, return_when=futures.ALL_COMPLETED)

    print(f"Published messages with error handler to {topic_path}.")

with airflow.DAG(
        'composer_sample_dag',
        'catchup=False',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=datetime.timedelta(days=1)) as dag:

    publish_handle = python_operator.PythonOperator(
        task_id='publish_handle',
        python_callable=publish_error_handle
    )

    publish_handle
```